# Putting round online indicator on a rounded avatar image

Tags: css

I am trying to create a round avatar image with a round online status indicator. 
This is result:
https://jsfiddle.net/65g28jnb/

As you can see I am putting avatar image as a background of "cbig" container but instead of this I would like to use something like this:

```
<img class="cbig" src="avatar.jpg" />
<div class="csmall"></div>
```

so that I don't have to put image as a background. Can somebody help?

```
<div class="cbig">
  <div class="csmall"></div>
</div>

<div class="cbig" style="
background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png);background-size:cover";>
  <div class="csmall"></div>
</div>


.cbig {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5%;
}
.csmall {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #99CC00;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use an inline image in the HTML...demostrate your issue with that.

Comment: If I could demonstrate, I would not post a question.

Comment: You demonstrate what you *tried* (even if it doesn't work) and we can help with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would mock this up using an `<img>` tag instead of an inline background image.

The trick is to use `object-fit:cover;` to maintain the correct ratio of the image despite being rounded.

```css
.c-avatar {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.c-avatar__image {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  object-fit:cover;
  border-radius:100%;
}
.c-avatar__status {
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:#99CC00;
  border:2px solid white;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:2%;
  right:2%;
  border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='c-avatar'>
  <img class='c-avatar__image' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542103749-8ef59b94f47e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80' alt=''>
  <span class='c-avatar__status'></span>
</div>
```